# Отправка данных с формы на хостинг и получение ответное письмо от хостинга на почту пользователя (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

есть форма на странице, где пользователь должен ввести свою почту и логин отправить на хостинг и получить ответное письмо от хостинга на свою почту. Как такое реализовать?  Буду благодарен за любые советы. Спасибо

Comment: Плагин Contact Forms 7.

Answer (score 1):

С помощью функции `mail`.

`mail(Получатель, Тема письма, Отправляемое сообщение);`